# CO2 leak at keg and regulator connection

Tags: beer, kegging, co2

First time kegging. I've run into an issue with a CO2 leak from the connection point between the regulator bolt and the tank. No matter the level of tightening of regulator to the tank.Even tried a different regulator. Same issue.

I've attached pictures of the tank and regulator.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I maybe missing another connector or washer on either the tank or regulator? Both regulators are brand new, it's gotta be a different issue on my side. Any help will be appreciated, got some beer that needs kegging right away!

Answer (score 1):

I had a leak a couple times between the regulator and tank. Notice that inner brass part in your first pic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uws1h.png).

[image]

You can stick an allen wrench in there and tighten it, or loosen it. On my regulator, I use this to adjust the compression on my nylon washer. Mine had backed itself out enough one day after removing it where tightening it did not allow it to seal completely. You may want to investigate that on yours. Maybe it's bottoming out before actually sealing on the threads.

Also, the regulators I've own had a nylon washer ([https://www.amazon.com/Learn-Brew-Nylon-Washers-Regulators/dp/B000DZFVDS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000DZFVDS)) in between the tank fitting and the regulator. Your's looks a little different, from memory, but here's a link to some other washers which are made to aid in sealing. These are single-use washers so be sure to replace it each time you swap tanks.

[https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Regulator-Washers-Centering-Fittings/dp/B07Q5VLSD5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q5VLSD5)

PS: I can't tell from the picture, but if you don't have a check valve on the output side of the regulator, consider putting one on. When you run out of co2, there isn't enough pressure differential to keep beer out of the co2 tank. The check valve prevents this. This is an inline one, there are other styles: https://www.morebeer.com/products/inline-check-valve.html